# Linux Kernel: Wait for other threads to complete

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel

I have a linux kernel module, I had to implement a TCP server and multiple clients to send some traffic. I had a question,

Now at the server end,  I have a main-kthread which spawns another kthread once it sees a TCP connection waiting to be Accepted. Now after the main kthread spawns say a couple of kthreads how can I put the main-kthread in wait state to make sure the other kthreads exit before the main-kthread can exit.

I am looking something similar to phtread-join semantics, but i need this in the Linux kernel space.

I could not find kthread_join as such, I am looking at alternatives. I did read about waitqueues. Hence was looking at interruptible_sleep_on() and wake_up().
But am unable to figure out how to use these API's.
For example,
In the main-thread, I do a interruptible_sleep_on, then who should wake him up? All the other threads, or the last thread? how do i figure who is the last thread exiting? Also how to make sure, the other threads have exited when this main-kthread is woken up.

Comment: Would you be ok with a solution that manually does that?

Comment: @shahbaz: I do not understand, could you please elaborate.

Comment: "how do i figure who is the last thread exiting?" just implement a counter which increments every time you create a thread and at thread exit, after decrementing it again, check if it is zero. if it is, the thread which is exiting was the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Wait queues are the right tools. There is a good description in [*Linux Device Drivers* (LDD)](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) [chapter 6](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch06.pdf). Here's a sketch of how your code might look like:

- Maintain a counter of server threads.
- Increment the counter just before spawning a server thread.
- When the server thread exists, decrease the counter.
- In the main thread, when exiting, wait on a wait queue until the counter value is 0.
- In the server threads, just after decreasing the counter, notify the main thread by signaling on the wait queue.

<sub>Warning: untested code, this is just a skeleton.</sub>

```
struct global_data {
    wait_queue_head_t wq;
    atomic_t thread_count;
};

main_thread () {
    global_data gd = {0};
    init_wait_queue_head(&gd.wq);
    while (serving) {
        …
        atomic_inc(&server_threads);
        if (IS_ERR_OR_NULL(kthread_create(server_thread, &gd)) {
            atomic_dec(&server_threads);
        }
    }
    wait_event_interruptible(&gd.wq, atomic_read(gd.thread_count) == 0);
    /* final cleanup */
}

server_thread (global_data *gd) {
    …
    atomic_dec(&gd->server_threads);
    wake_up(&gd->wq);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I do not think that this is a clean solution. What will you do if the last thread stops its execution right after the `wake_up(&gd->wq)` call before it exits and the main thread wakes up, with the count being 0, and wants to clean up even though the thread is still running?

Comment: @Papergay I assume that the problem is the resources that the server thread has been using. Decreasing the counter must happen after it's freed all the resources. What could be the problem if the thread still exists but holds no resource?

Comment: I wouldnt know what problem there should be if all the resources are freed, but I thought the exit might internally invoke other stuff. Well however, one should be aware of the possibility to not encounter any surprising behaviour, in my opinion. That is what I wanted to point out actially. Or do you think that it is entirely neglectable?